# How to stop request when fields is empty using keyUp&keyDown after deleting values

Tags: php, jquery

Request keeps sending after input has been deleted and shows all the result queried.
How can I stop sending after all inputs are empty?

This is my code:

```
var typingTimer;          
var doneTypingInterval = 3000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

    $('#formsearch').find(':input').each(function(){
          $(this).keyup(function(){
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        });
    })

    $('#formsearch').find(':input').each(function(){
         $(this).keydown(function(){
         clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        });
    })
    //on keydown, clear the countdown 

    //user is "finished typing," do something
    function doneTyping () {
    var name = $('#fname').val();
    var p = $('#persona').val();
    var c = $('#comp').val();

    $.get("?task=body&wtd=searchlead&fname="+name+"&comp="+c+"&per="+p,
       function(data){
    if(data != ""){

        $('#result').html(data);

        } else {

        $('#result').html("No matching records");

        }
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code

```
 return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#formsearch').find(':input').each(function(){

          $(this).keyup(function(){
            // Added the check  
            if($(this).val().length>0)
              typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        });
    })
```